# How to jump from a line in a .ps file to the corresponding line in the .tex file

Tags: compiling, forward-inverse-search, postscript

I have TeXnicCenter and GSview. If I have a `.tex` file `house.tex`, and the resulting PostScript file `house.ps`, I'd like to be able to jump from a line in `house.ps` to the corresponding line in `house.tex` quickly.

Comment: What makes you believe this is possible? Synchronisation is possible to the direct output from TeX, so a `.dvi` or `.pdf` file depending on how you are working. But that I know of this is not going to work for a PostScript file (or indeed a `.pdf` generated using `dvips` + `ps2dpf` or using `dvipdfm(x)`).

Comment: I'm baffled why you stick with *PostScript* in 2012. Why don't you use PDF?

Comment: Sorry, if you have them, both solutions for .pdf and .ps are also ok. The reason I use .ps is that if I am reading my .ps and then I compile again, gsview stands in the same page, whereas If I do the same thing with .pdf i have to open the file again and go manually tothe page I was reading.

Comment: There should be the equivalent of a `-synctex` option that will allow you to right click on the code and just to the appropriate place in the PDF and also in the reverse direction (which is more useful). See [Location inside a LaTeX source code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28281/location-inside-a-latex-source-code/28282#28282)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronisation is possible to the direct output from TeX, so a `.dvi` or `.pdf` file, depending on how you are working. But that I know of this is not going to work for a PostScript file (or indeed a `.pdf` generated using dvips + ps2dpf or using dvipdfm(x)). The synchronisation information if lost on conversion from `.dvi` format.