# Conflict between TikZ and *.cls file

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I am attempting to convert a document from one class to another.  In the original class, I am able to use TikZ and PGFPlots for my graphics.  However, in the new class, I receive the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.51 \section{Introduction}
```

If I remove all of the `\section{}` commands, the document compiles fine.  Furthermore, the `\section*{}` commands do not cause an error.

The class `.cls` file for which I am experiencing the errors can be found at: https://bitbucket.org/lgriffiths/lyx-classes/src/df41b5298566/_miktex_tex_latex/ifasd/ifasd.cls

## MWE

```
\documentclass{ifasd}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\section*{Testing One}
\lipsum[1]

\section*{Testing Two}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Testing Three}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be much easier for us to help you if you post a MWE that illustrates the error.  To see what's entailed in a MWE look at [What makes a good MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will include a MWE from now on.

Comment: It seems the issue arises with `tikz` or `pstricks`.  Also, it seems that the package `titlesec` seems to be the culprit.  But, I haven't found anything in my searches about why the `titlesec` package should create problems with either `tikz` or `pstricks`.

Comment: An `article` class document which uses the packages `titlesec`, `lipsum`, and `tikz` seems to think there's a missing parenthesis when using the `\titleformat` command and calling `\MakeUppercase` in the manner called by your class.

Comment: As a work around, I removed the \MakeUppercase in the \titleformat command and typed my section headings in uppercase within the *.tex document.  Its a brute-force type solution, but it works for now.  I will post a more elegant solution if I come up with one.

Answer (score 4):

There is an error in the specification for the section titles: the `\MakeUppercase` instruction should go in the *last* mandatory argument of `\titleformat`. Where it is now it doesn't make sense.

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {6pt}
  {\MakeUppercase}
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
\documentclass{ifasd}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]%
  {\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries\uppercase}%
  {\thesection}{6pt}{}
\begin{document}
[ ... ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Whittling down `ifasd`, the following MWE has an apparent conflict between `tikz` (or `pstricks`) and how `\MakeUppercase` is being used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]%
  {\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
  {\thesection}{6pt}{}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Testing One}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Here's a bit of a work around until someone comes up with a better solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]%
  {\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}%
  {\thesection}{6pt}{}
%..%'
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand\section{ som }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
        {\oldsection*{#3}}
        {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
         {\oldsection{\MakeUppercase{#3}}}
         {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}}}
%..%'
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

%\MakeUppercase This one
\section{Testing One}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

So, in terms of your class, you can write something along the lines of

```
\documentclass{ifasd}
%..%'
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand\section{ som }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
        {\oldsection*{#3}}
        {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
         {\oldsection{\MakeUppercase{#3}}}
         {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}}}
%..%'
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\section*{Testing One}
\lipsum[1]

\section*{Testing Two}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Testing Three}{}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

provided you've gone into `ifasd` and removed the apparently confounding `\MakeUppercase` from the `\titleformat` commands.

The idea for writing `\section` this way is due to an answer by @egreg
to [a question of mine.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111641/22413)