# Setting \pagestyle{fancy} seems into create an error

Tags: header-footer, conditionals, fancyhdr

Calling `fancy` page style is somehow apparently causing the following condition to test true.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\ifcsname chapter\endcsname%
    \renewcommand{\chapter}{}
\fi
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
testing
\end{document}
```

If I place `\pagestyle{fancy}` after the conditional, `\ifcsname chapter....\fi`, everything works.  This is an `article` class, so this conditional should be false.  If I call `\pagestyle{plain}`, it doesn't matter where I place it.

Why does this order matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page style `fancy` (`\ps@fancy`) contains:

```
\@ifundefined{chapter}{...}{...}
```

That is the LaTeX test for undefined:

```
\def\@ifundefined#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
```

`\csname` has the side effect that it defines an undefined command with the meaning `\relax`:

```
\show\chapter
\pagestyle{fancy}% \@ifundefined{chapter}{...}{...}
\show\chapter
```

The meaning of `\chapter` changes:

```
> \chapter=undefined.
l.3 \show\chapter

? 
> \chapter=\relax.
l.5 \show\chapter
```

Now `\chapter` is defined for e-TeX's `\ifcsname` and `\renewcommand{\chapter}{}` is called that again used the LaTeX idea of undefined: A command is undefined if it is undefined or has the meaning of `\relax`. As result `\renewcommand` complains that `\chapter is not defined.

e-TeX's `\ifcsname` does not have the side effect and lets the command untouchted. (Also it is internally optimized in the sense that it does not create a hash table entry.)

The test needs to be a little longer:

```
\ifcsname chapter\endcsname
  \ifx\chapter\relax
  \else
    \renewcommand\chapter{}
  \fi
\fi
```

A defined `\chapter` might confuse packages and macros about the capabilities of the class (`article` does not have chapters). If the purpose of the mysterious `\renewcommand\chapter{}` is to *undefine* chapter, then it will fail, because `\chapter` remains defined with the meaning of an empty macro.
A command can be undefined by assigning it to an undefined macro:

```
\ifcsname chapter\endcsname
  \let\chapter\UnDeFiNeD
\fi
```

Comment: So, I gather `\ifcsname` does not have this side-effect?  I ask because I'd already used `\ifcsname chapter\endcsname` at least once earlier in my original file.  But there was never a complaint when compiling.

Comment: Actually, `\renewcommand\chapter{}` was just for the MWE.  In the actual document I'm doing something more along the lines of what @egreg was suggesting regarding http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111641/22413 an earlier question of mine).  I would like my *package* to be versatile enough to define things correctly whether the class is `article`, `book`, etc.